# OpenLayers 3 doesn't want to draw programmatically a polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 3 and I am trying to draw a polygon using given coordinates, but it doesn't want to draw it.

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector();

            var ring = [
             [3139880.24789847, 5961935.332187176], [3179627.5026067616, 5972025.01992082],
             [3146606.706387566, 5927997.291628557], [3186353.9610958574, 5939615.719927904]];

            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: source,
                type: 'Polygon',
                geometryFunction: ring,
            });

            draw.on('drawend', function (e) {
                var id = guid();
                e.feature.featureID = id;
                e.feature.setProperties({
                    'id': id,
                    'name': 'Polygon',
                    'description': 'Some values'
                })
                map.removeInteraction(draw);
            });
            map.addInteraction(draw);
```

Comment: Someone has had success here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210362/open-layers-3-how-to-draw-a-polygon-programmically. One thing to fix is that your ring is not closed.

Comment: i used that method there but couldn't click on feature , after created

Answer (score 3):

Try as follow:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector();
var ring = ...
var geometry = ol.geom.Polygon([ring]);
var feature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: geometry,
});
source.addFeature(feature);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ring = [[77.4700927734375, 12.906190219892437],[77.4707794189453, 12.987162237749473],[77.5188446044922, 12.989838549012532],[77.51060485839844, 12.961066692801282],[77.51747131347656, 12.953705916047227],[77.52708435058594, 12.94500653581774],[77.51815795898438, 12.936306851970144],[77.50030517578125, 12.92426063498786],[77.486572265625, 12.912883118595701],[77.4700927734375, 12.906190219892437]];
var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([ring]);
polygon.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');     
var feature = new ol.Feature(polygon);

// Create vector source and the feature to it.
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

// Create vector layer attached to the vector source.
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

// Add the vector layer to the map.
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

This will work.