# How to programmatically start drawing in OpenLayers 4._

Tags: javascript, openlayers, events, map-drawing

In openlayers there are 2 paradigms for drawing features one is to create a "draw interaction" that lets the user draw a feature and the other is to create the geometry and feature yourself--then add it to the layer.

I would like to programmatically start a polygon "interaction" drawing for the user by placing the first point. After which the user will place the remaining points. It therefore must be an "interaction".

This means I must simulate a user click or draw event that the openlayers api accepts as valid.

I've tried..

```
map.dispatchEvent(<clickevent>)
map.dispatchEvent(<drawstartevent>)

/*draw being ol.interaction.Draw*/
draw.dispatchEvent(<clickevent>)
draw.dispatchEvent(<drawstartevent>)
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160545/openlayers-3-doesnt-want-to-draw-programmatically-a-polygon

Comment: That question is about programmatic drawing. Not placing points as part of a user draw "interaction". They are very different. I'll try to update the question for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

In non minified (ol-debug) version you can use function startDrawing_ (doc is [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.3.4/src/ol/interaction/draw.js#L474)) which accepts event as a parametr. It uses only coordinates from that event, so it could be replaced by a simple object. Problem is I dont know how is this function named in minified version and also that name could change in time. Also it is not a very clean approach...

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({features:new ol.Collection([]), type:"Polygon"});
map.addInteraction(draw);
draw.startDrawing_({coordinates:[111,222]});
```

Comment: this breaks with version of openlayers newer than 6.1.1 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10731

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ol.interaction.Draw.handleEvent` method for that. Its documentation says:

> ... may actually draw or finish the drawing.

See: [ol.interaction.Draw API doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html).

Comment: That fires when there is a user "Draw" event in response to a user's input. It does not allow one to programmatically draw the first point in a user draw "interaction".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.mapRef is this.$refs.$map` if you are working in vue-layers. For pure javascript use "new Draw".

```
const Draw = this.mapRef.getInteractionById('drawByClick')
Draw.addToDrawing_({ coordinate: [x,y] })
```

or to start drawing

```
Draw.startDrawing_({ coordinate: [x,y] })
```

my specific code that work in vue:
pls dont be like me and dont use try catch. just check if drawing has started

```
try {
        this.mapRef.getInteractionById('drawByClick').addToDrawing_({ coordinate: this.mapRef.$view.getCenter() })
} catch {
        this.mapRef.getInteractionById('drawByClick').startDrawing_({ coordinate: this.mapRef.$view.getCenter() })
}
```